# A little next combination program in C++

Tags: c++, combinatorics

An implementation of next combination function at *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, Rosen* p.438.

### How it works:

Input:

1. The size n of a integer set {1, 2, ..., n}, which is where you choose objects from.
2. The size r of the subset of the integer set you currently have.
3. A pointer to the subset you currently have.

Output: The next subset in lexicographic order.

If you want to play around here is a link to [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/yOYQuz).

---

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

// C(n, r) and provide the current subset a of size r.
bool nextCombination(int n, int r, int *a);
void printArray(int *a, int n);

int main() {
    int a[] = {1,2,3}; // So the current subset is {1,2,3} of size 3.
    int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    int count = 0;
    // The following example is C(7,3), start at {1,2,3}
    do {
        printArray(a, length);
        count++;
    } while (nextCombination(7, length, a));
    cout << "Total: " << count << '\n'; // Since we start from {1,2,3}, all C(7,3) subsets are generated and counted. The answer should be 7!/(3!4!)=35
    return 0;
}

bool nextCombination(int n, int r, int *a) {
    int lastNotEqualOffset = r-1;
    while (a[lastNotEqualOffset] == n-r+(lastNotEqualOffset+1)) {
        lastNotEqualOffset--;
    }
    if (lastNotEqualOffset < 0) {
        cout << "the end\n";
        return false;
    }
    a[lastNotEqualOffset]++;
    for (int i = lastNotEqualOffset+1; i<r; i++) {
        a[i] = a[lastNotEqualOffset]+(i-lastNotEqualOffset);
    }
    return true;
}

void printArray(int *a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The overview of its output:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
1 2 6 
1 2 7 
1 3 4 
...
4 5 6 
4 5 7 
4 6 7 
5 6 7 
the end
Total: 35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using std::cout;`, while better than including the entire namespace, is still worse than simply using the `std::` prefix. If typing it annoys you too much, you can just make a macro in your editor to type it for you when you press a certain key combo.

Overall this looks much more like a C program than a C++ one. Assuming your algorithm works as intended you can take some steps to make this more C++ idiomatic?

- Replace the array with a vector and get rid of raw pointers.
- Enforce const when possible.
- Drop `return 0` from `main` because the compiler will generate it for you. This refers excplicitly to the `return 0` at the end of `main`. [Exiting from `main` by reaching the end automatically returns 0](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.3.html). So adding the `return` statement is just duplicate code.
- [Prefer prefix over postfix operator](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/59880).
- Move the logic into a class so you don't have to pass everything on every call to `nextCombination`.
- You can overload `operator<<` to print the current line.
- Eliminate magic numbers.

Keeping all this in mind, the rewrite could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class Combinatorics {
public:
    Combinatorics(std::vector<int> const& v, int const& n, int const& r)
        : elements{v}
        , n{n}
        , r{r}
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Combinatorics const& obj);

    bool next() {
        int lastNotEqualOffset = r - 1;
        while (elements[lastNotEqualOffset] == n - r + (lastNotEqualOffset + 1)) {
            --lastNotEqualOffset;
        }
        if (lastNotEqualOffset < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ++elements[lastNotEqualOffset];
        for (int i = lastNotEqualOffset + 1; i < r; ++i) {
            elements[i] = elements[lastNotEqualOffset] + (i - lastNotEqualOffset);
        }
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> elements;
    int n;
    int r;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Combinatorics const& obj) {
    std::copy(obj.elements.begin(), obj.elements.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
    return os;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int n = 7;
    constexpr int r = 3;
    int total = 0;
    Combinatorics combinatorics{{1, 2, 3}, n, r};
    do {
        std::cout << combinatorics << "\n";
        ++total;
    } while (combinatorics.next());
    std::cout << total << "\n";
}
```

You simply pass all your data into the constructor upfront and then call `next` until every repetition has been done. (I kept `n` and `r` because they are used in the math context, normally you should try to avoid short variable names like that).

Comment: Why `using std::cout` is still worse than `std::`? Btw, I can't still not fully understand why many people recommend to drop `return 0` from main. Isn't that against the principle of least astonishment? I mean, if I a see a function that has an `int` in its declaration, I expect to see a return somewhere in the definition of such function. Why `main` should have a different treatment?

Comment: @Xam I will edit the post to explain about `return 0` in more detail. Regarding `using std::cout`, it still pollutes the namespace just on a smaller scale.